# Designing web forms for tablets

Tags: html, forms, touchscreen

Does anyone know of any documentation, best practises, frameworks, blog posts or good example sites for building usable html forms for touchscreens?

I am building a web interface for entering data into a database which will be mostly used on tablet devices. Technicians standing up with the tablet in one hand will inspect vehicles and fill in a questionaire on the tablet as they do so.

Up until now I have been building e-commerce websites for use on "normal" computers, so HTML forms, javascript and server side validation are everyday things for me. I'm searching for information specificly about how to optimise forms for touchscreen use.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better fit on [ui.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You should ask this on ux/ui stack exchange sites since backend is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is reading some articles about html forms for mobile devices as most of the smart phones are touch screen:

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-html40-mobile/

http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/best_practices_for_the_mobile_web/